# How can I recover my hard disk data that got erased when I tried to setup Ubuntu?

Tags: data-recovery

I tried to install Ubuntu in my laptop that had windows 7 and I chose 'erase partition' as I was thinking it will erase the C partition only so as to make it the Ubuntu drive .After restart I found the whole hard disk mounted as one partition with no data .So is there any way to return back my data or is it impossible?

Comment: Try testdisk but it may recover some amount of datas not fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can do restore your deleted data(mostly).

first i advise you not to do anything on the harddisk now.

All you need is a recovery software. for me i advise you to use [r-linux](http://www.r-tt.com/data_recovery_linux/).

Answer (score -3):

It's too late. It isn't going to be recoverable. It has been formatted there is simply no way to get it back, this is why we recommend a backup before you start.

Comment: ever heard of testdisk? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: This is not technically accurate. It's often possible to recover quite a lot.

Comment: From experience it is. I have always had issues recovering data.